# Can't fetch data from sqlite to spinner in alert dialog

Tags: android, database, sqlite, spinner, android-spinner

I hope somebody can help me find out why the following code does not work with me. I have a method to fetch all names from database table, and I use List to get them. this is my code to fetch them

```
/*fetch all names to spinner*/
public List<String> readAllNames()
{
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] allNames = {SQLiteHelper.Names};
    String selection = SQLiteHelper.Names + " LIKE ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    cursor = database.query(SQLiteHelper.LECTURE_NAME, allNames, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.Names)));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return names;
}
```

This is my code to call the method and fill my spinner

```
datasource.openToRead();
    List<String> names = datasource.readAllNames();
    ArrayAdapter<String> spin = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Home.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names);
    spin.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ins_jadname.setAdapter(spin);
    datasource.close();
```

the problem is the spinner empty, does everybody know what is wrong with my code? I don't wanna use simple cursor adapter, because I think is more simple.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you tested the names list if it has any values after querying the database?

Comment: not yet, how do I check it?

Comment: Just use a `Log` line : `Log.e("LOOK_FOR_ME", "The size of the list is " + names.size());` (insert it after closing the `Cursor` in the `readAllNames()` method. Then look in the Logcat to see the size of the list.

Comment: well the result is 0, do you have any idea how to fix my code?

Comment: well thank you @Luksprog I've solved this, I used rawQuery method to query my data.

Comment: If you want to get all names than it doesn't make any sense to use the sqlite `like` selection, just query the database for all values: `cursor = database.query(SQLiteHelper.LECTURE_NAME, allNames, null, null, null, null, null);`

Comment: well thank you for your suggest, thanks you so much. btw would you like to me you last comment to be answer so I can vote it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all the names from the database there is no need to use the `LIKE` selection clause in the `readAllNames()` method, you just need to get the data from the name column from all the rows of the target sqlite table. The code would be:

```
cursor = database.query(SQLiteHelper.LECTURE_NAME, allNames, null, null, null, null, null);
```